# Question about Drude's model of conduction

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, conductors

Why is it proper to assume the electronic velocity after collision is zero in Drude's model?
(Where are momentum and energy conservation?)

Answer (score 1):

The standard assumption is that immediately after a collision, the velocity of an electron is *random* (not zero). Random here means the electron can have any velocity, with probabilities given by [the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), consistent with the temperature of the lattice at the point of collision. Since in the absence of external fields or a temperature gradient, electrons come to equilibrium through collisions, and since (classically) the velocities of non-interacting electrons have the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution at equilibrium, this is a simple but reasonable assumption consistent with the equilibrium state. It isn't necessarily a correct assumption, but it is simple model of how electrons achieve equilibrium and facilitates some useful calculations. The mean of the equilibrium velocity distribution is zero, so the *average* velocity of an electron after a collision is zero in the Drude model.

In general the energy and momentum of an electron are not conserved in collisions, because it can exchange energy and momentum with the lattice of ions that make up the crystal. Energy transfer from electrons to the lattice is why a metal heats up when you pass current through it. The fact that electrons lose momentum to the lattice is why solids don't have infinite electrical conductivity.